# Adding a virtual destructor bloats code size

Tags: c++, gcc, arm

I'm fooling around with c++ on arm cortex m3 with latest available arm-none-eabi-gcc 6.3.
I made a dummy class and created a global object of that class:

```cpp
class B
{};

class A : B
{
public:
    A()
    {
        RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN;
        GPIOC->CRH = 1;
        GPIOC->ODR |= 1<<8;    
    }

    virtual void foo()
    {}

    virtual ~A()
    {}
};

A a;

int main(void) { while(1); }
```

This code compiles to 1620 bytes. If I remove virtual dtor it compiles to 1304 bytes. That's a palpable difference.

I went and looked into assembly and .map file and saw that many different runtime functions are being linked to my binary if I use virtual dtor. There's malloc and free and _static_initialization_and_destruction and so on.

The strange thing is: I do not understand how are they called? Main is called like this:

```
 8000260:   d3f9        bcc.n   8000256 <FillZerobss>
 8000262:   f000 f89f   bl  80003a4 <SystemInit>
 8000266:   f000 f957   bl  8000518 <__libc_init_array>
 800026a:   f000 f865   bl  8000338 <main>
 800026e:   4770        bx  lr
```

After return from main (which never happens, by the way) execution just sits there on bx lr, it keeps jumping to the same address.

So I can't see a path for static object deinitialization to be called. Why isn't it optimized away as unreachable code?

I compile like this:
`arm-none-eabi-g++ -c -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics`
and link like this `arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb --specs=nosys.specs  --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections -T "${ProjDirPath}/src/Startup/STM32F100XB_FLASH.ld" -ffreestanding`

I tried adding -fno-use-cxa-atexit or making a dummy `__cxa_atexit` - and it does make binary *slightly* smaller (which is even weirder than no effect at all).

Is there any way to disable destruction of static objects completely?

**UPDATE:**

- adding -Os made code shrink but there is still a difference with/without virtual dtor (1244 vs 1040 bytes ) so the question remains.
- here's the output of compiling with -S [with dtor](https://gist.github.com/Amomum/0ed8890f76d97172e7ddc10e9ae1c174), [without dtor](https://gist.github.com/Amomum/1a1e472142cfcff7f2be6c117e3f8152)

Comment: Infinite loops that don't have side effects are undefined behavior, and can be terminated if I recall correctly. There was an example of it that "disproved" Fermat's Last Theorem by having an infinite loop end.

Comment: Why would you add a virtual destructor for that case? You only need virtual destructor when you delete a pointer to a base class.

Comment: Can you share the compilation result of `-S` (instead of `-c`), with and without the virtual destructor? So we can check out what is compiled exactly.

Comment: You don't appear to have turned on any optimisation.

Comment: @JamesRoot that's funny. Infinite loop with no side effects does sound like the most defined behaviour ever :)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot that's just an example, I'm trying to figure out what's happening.

Comment: @geza I have updated the question.

Comment: @Amomum did you find the answer?

Comment: @peku33 sorry, no. gcc is not my main compiler so I kinda lost interest.

Answer (score 0):

Without whole-program optimization, it is not clear that the destructor is actually unreachable.  There could be another translation unit with a constructor that spawns a thread which later calls the `exit` function.

Comment: Fair enough. Although I tried -flto and the code got even bigger. Anyway, is there any way to get rid of that unnecessary teardown code?

Comment: Do you need any global constructors or destructs? You could probably remove `init`/`fini` sections with a linker script.

Comment: well, I don't need global destructs - hence my question. But I do need global constructors, I use static objects quite often. I'm not very good with gcc linker syntax, can it be done with some compiling/linking options?